# How to use input field inside docking panel of autodesk viewer api?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I was trying to add an increment & decrement counter input inside of a docking panel in Autodesk viewer.

I even tried with a basic text input field within it. It's not working. The panel along with the input field is getting displayed fine. But why am I not able to use it. Like if it's an input field I am not enabled, not able to type or change it's value. In case of the counter, the same.

Is it done purposely? If so I have seen applications using such counter like inputs. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my approach?

The code sample which I was trying given below,

**Screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyEBr.png

**Note: I've also tried with a simple text input field in the place of the counter, it works the same way**

Edit: Disabling the move handler from the container solved this issue.Comment from samuel-middendorp helped.

```
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            #forgeViewer {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: #F0F8FF;
            }

            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
    </body>
   <script>

   var viewer;
   var closable = null;
    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
        getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
            var token = 'access token';
            var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
            onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
        }
    };

SimplePanel = function(parentContainer, id, title, content, x, y)
{
  this.content = content;
Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.call(this, parentContainer, id, title,{shadow:false});

// Auto-fit to the content and don't allow resize.  Position at the coordinates given.

this.container.style.height = "250px";
this.container.style.width = "450px";
this.container.style.resize = "auto";
this.container.style.left = x + "px";
this.container.style.top = y + "px"; 
this.container.style.zIndex = 2;

};

SimplePanel.prototype = Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.prototype);
SimplePanel.prototype.constructor = SimplePanel;

SimplePanel.prototype.initialize = function()
{ 
        this.title = this.createTitleBar(this.titleLabel || this.container.id);
this.container.appendChild(this.title);

this.container.appendChild(this.content);
this.initializeMoveHandlers(this.container);

this.closer = document.createElement("span");
this.closer = this.createCloseButton();
this.initializeCloseHandler(this.closer);
this.container.appendChild(this.closer);

var op = {left:false,heightAdjustment:45,marginTop:0};
this.scrollcontainer = this.createScrollContainer(op);

var id = viewer.getSelection();
var dataItem;
var data = [
    {
        id:"2648",
        name:"Chiller",
        temp:"300 deg",
        serviceReq:5,
        reservations:"3"
    },
    {
        id:"2228",
        name:"Door",
        temp:"150 deg",
        serviceReq:2,
        reservations:"4"
    },
    {
        id:"2198",
        name:"Cooler",
        temp:"400 deg",
        serviceReq:6,
        reservations:"2"
    }
]

data.forEach(item => {
    if(item.id == id){
        dataItem = item;
    }
})

//this is the portion I have the issue - here I appending an input tag inside of a table cell. But the problem is the input field is not focussing,can't able to edit, not enabled 

var html = [
    '<table>',
    '<thead>',
    '<th>Key</th><th>Value</th>',
    '</thead>',
    '<tbody>',
    '<tr><td>ID</td><td>'+dataItem.id+'</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Name</td><td>'+dataItem.name+'</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Temperature</td><td>'+dataItem.temp+'</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Service Requests</td><td contenteditable="true"> <input type=“text”/></td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Reservations</td><td>'+dataItem.reservations+'</td></tr>',
    '</tbody>',
    '</table>',
].join('\n');


$(this.scrollContainer).append(html);

this.initializeMoveHandlers(this.title);    
};

    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {   
    var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv,{ extensions: ['CustomPropertyPanelExtension'] });
    var startedCode = viewer.start();
    if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
    }

    console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

});

var documentId = 'urn:my urn';
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {

    var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
    viewer.addEventListener( Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, event=>{

        if( closable != null ) {
           closable.uninitialize();
           closable = null;
        }
        var content = document.createElement('div');
        var mypanel = new  SimplePanel(NOP_VIEWER.container,'mypanel','Asset properties',content,20,20);
        closable = mypanel;
        mypanel.setVisible(true);
})
}

function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
    console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
}
   </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) If you can. theres a lot going on in this code and hard to narrow down.

Comment: I have edited my code - simplified a bit. Also, I pin portion even simplified here

`var html = [
 ‘<div>’
 ‘<input type=“text”/>’
 ‘</div>’
 ].join('\n');
`

Comment: Also added a screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyEBr.png

Comment: Going forward you can create a minimally reproducible example on jsbin/codepen or any platform of choice similar to [this](https://jsbin.com/lirigeq/edit) oi [this](https://codepen.io/petrbroz/pen/BaaebgJ) to help us look into the issues and i'd strongly suggest to consult a colleague/friend/(web dev)community with minimal exposure to web dev for quicker/fuller response to your questions(as they tend to be more concerned with front end dev in general than Forge or Viewer) so as not to impede your progress...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

If you insist on making the scroll container draggable which looks quite anti-intuitive to me you can easily stop the events (mousedown) on the input from being captured/intercepts by the handlers enabled on the container (which brings us back to the anti-pattern way the panel handlers would capture the events instead of letting them bubble up though ...

See the updated [sample here](https://jsbin.com/teyetow/edit?js)

```
inputElement.addEventListener('mousedown',e=>e.stopPropagation())
```

**Original Answer**

Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce the issues with my own sample [here](https://jsbin.com/duqumix/edit?js) - the input functions as it's intended in the panel:

[image: Node.js]

```
innerHTML=[
    '<table>',
    '<thead>',
    '<th>Key</th><th>Value</th>',
    '</thead>',
    '<tbody>',
    '<tr><td>ID</td><td>233</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Name</td><td>233</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Temperature</td><td>233</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Service Requests</td><td contenteditable="true"> <input type=“text”/></td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Reservations</td><td>233</td></tr>',
    '</tbody>',
    '</table>',
].join('\n')
```

Looks like the issue is not exactly reproducible w/o your other code and/or CSS that might have been problematic so can you clone and add your own code to reproduce the error and comment below so I know to check??

**EDIT**

Still couldn't to replicate the issue ... tried your live demo (working one [here](https://jsbin.com/teyetow/edit?js), yours has expired ...) on both Firefox (62.0) and Chrome (81) and the inputs were working as expected:

[image]

Comment: Can you check this one, please 

https://jsbin.com/vivodaq/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: It opens a docking panel on click of a node, refer above image link for the portion clicked

Comment: Disabling move handlers fixes the issue for some reason. Maybe the move handler listens for a click in the panel ? and thus overwrites any other action from taking place in the panel ? Disabling the move handlers on your container (or rather not adding them at all) still allows the panel to be moved when clicking on its titlebar.

Comment: @Bryan Seems to me the original one initialised move handlers on the container that is inside the panel. Thus this makes the whole panel movable, even from inside the container. Removing these (or not adding them) fixes the problem. The new jsbin you posted indeed has the `initializemovehandlers` line commented. If you add it back the panel can be moved from anywhere in the panel but we loose any other click functionality.